# Replace @SequenceGenerator since its deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence-generators

I have a problem with `@SequenceGenerator`:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="pk_user_id", sequenceName="seq_user_id", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="pk_user_id")
```

When the application starts up it shows warning:

> > WARN 7388 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details

I tried to find out how I can replace a deprecated code with a new one but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to the warning message and Hibernate documentation ([Hibernate deprecated list](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/deprecated-list.html)) you should use [SequenceStyleGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html). Or better use [@GenericGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) and specify generator strategy.

Here is a typical example of usage:

```
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "wikiSequenceGenerator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "WIKI_SEQUENCE"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "wikiSequenceGenerator")
```

Comment: What if the annotations are from JPA ?

Comment: If using Hibernate 4, one can change a property without changing code `properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");` (see [Vlad Mihalcea blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/07/15/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/)). However hibernate 5 is using the enhanced generators by default so no need for that property.

Comment: Those new sequence generators are using _optimisers_, and the default is the `pooled` one and if this is problematic, you can still avoid issues by using the previous algorythm if you set hibernate to use the **hi/lo** optimizer, for exemple set  `properties.put("hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred", "hilo");`. The benefit is still that there's no change in the code that is using JPA annotations.

Comment: i've received 28 messages like this. after changes still receive 28 messages llike this, so, for some reason, did not work for me :(

Comment: If upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4.x, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39244191/3109776)

Comment: Hi, What is allocationSize here in new wikiSequenceGenerator ?

Comment: Should be [50](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/jpa/orm_2_1.xsd)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
```

A colleague had added it by mistake, and it was not needed. After removing it the warning logs were removed.

Hope this helps someone.