# deprecated SequenceHiLoGenerator sequence-based id generator; use SequenceStyleGenerator instead

Tags: java, hibernate

my application is logging

> org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of
>   deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id
>   generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
>   instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.

There is a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861098/replace-sequencegenerator-since-its-deprecated) that fix the problem, but my question is if it's possible replace the Sequence generator org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
to org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator without go throught every single domain class annotations writing a custom @GenericGenerator? Something like a property maybe...

My code has something like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_name")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_name", sequenceName="hibernate_sequence")
private Long id;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `true`, which is the default in Hibernate 5, and that should disable the legacy behavior and automatically selecting the enhanced generator.

Comment: It works, but now i have another error: 
Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting toset conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [50] and [1]

Comment: I hope you might have already found this fix but still i mention here so that others can take reference. Your sequence generator in your entities have different incrementSize value 50 and 1. You need to adapt them to have only one incrementSize say 50.

Comment: @LucasOliveira I'm getting this too. Did you find a solution? Since the last time it worked properly, I recently added a couple new entities which must somehow be setting an increment value of 1, but I don't know how. I only see this value set in one place, to 50, here: https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application/blob/blogwithkotlin/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml#L13