# use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator] and Unique constratint violations when jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings:true

Tags: hibernate, jpa

After upgrading to Hibernate 5 I am getting the error `Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator]`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861098/replace-sequencegenerator-since-its-deprecated) which has a code snippet mentioning how to solve the problem.

- I would like to know how that solution works. Does that code snippet do the same thing as the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation? If so why was the `SequenceGenerator` deprecated?
- My annotations are from `javax.persistence` package. I would prefer to not add hibernate specific stuff in my code. In the answer I have linked there is `strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",` which is hibernate dependent(at least on the runtime). Is there a way to achieve this?
- When I set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings:true` I get unique constraint violation errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question,

The above deprecation warning comes because Spring Boot 1.5 sets 
`jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false`. If it was set to true, Hibernate will internally use the `SequenceStyleGenerator` and the warning will not come.

But there would be a difference in the logic that is executed to get the next value of the sequence.

- With the above setting set to false, `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator` would have been used, and this does not seem to use the `allocationSize` parameter of `@SequenceGenerator`. It will always call the database to get the next value of the sequence. There is another `SequenceHiLoGenerator` and quoting from its [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/SequenceHiLoGenerator.html), `An IdentifierGenerator that combines a hi/lo algorithm with an underlying oracle-style sequence that generates hi values.` So this can be used together with `INCREMENT BY` when creating the Orcale Sequence and that generator would not call the database for each insert.
- With the above setting set to true, Hibernate will by default use a [`PooledOptimizer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/PooledOptimizer.html) which does use `allocationSize` parameter. Due to this difference in how the ids are generated, I got the unique constraint violation error.

Comment: For Spring Boot a property is: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true